# Scoot has me registered as a non-EU resident

Tags: eu-citizens, scoot

[image]I booked a flight with Scoot from Athens to Berlin. I am a Greek citizen. For some reason, although I never wrote this anywhere, on my residency there is this phrase: *I am not residing in the EU or Switzerland*.

I obviously am residing in the EU, since I live in Greece. Should I try and contact them about this? Will I have a problem boarding?

Comment: Can you provide a photo/screenshot of where you see this message, with all sensitive info edited out?

Comment: On your residency?

Comment: Yes it is in my personal details next to residency.

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: I wonder what this could possibly be used for... But can you use the "Edit" button to change it?

Comment: @jcaron GDPR, see the update to my answer

Answer (score 7):

No, it doesn’t matter. As long as you present a valid ID any airline would board you regardless of what your ticket says about your citizenship or residency. Relax and enjoy the flight.

Scoot only uses this information for managing [GDPR compliance](https://www.flyscoot.com/en/privacy), it doesn't affect their actual flight operations in any way.

Comment: Ok! Thanx everyone!!!